# How store a huge amount of data (Integers)?

Tags: sql, database, matrix, optimization, bigdata

I have a set of data. Each element in the dataset consists of a Matrix (8x4), and 48 integers.

I need to store around 10^20 such elements.

Elements in the matrix can be only one of the elements {0,1,2,3,4}

Currently I am planning to store it as an SQL database, with 50 columns.

- ID [INT]
- MATRIX (matrix elements stored as a single integer)     [BIGINT]
- and 48 integer columns [INT]

I've tried generating a dummy database consisting of 10 million tuples and I got a database of size approximately 35 MB

But it is not acceptable since the final database will be of size 35 x 10^13 MB

The bigint of the matrix is currently determined like this, For a matrix

```
1    2    3    4
1    2    3    4
0    0    0    0
3    2    1    4
1    0    3    1
4    0    3    2
0    4    2    4
1    1    0    2
```

the value in column MATRIX will be like 
12341234000032141031403204241102

Question 1:

- Is there a better way to store such a data? (Data Models)

Question 2:

- Is there a way to represent this matrix in a more space conserving manner?

Question 3:

- Is there any other way is can represent this data other than SQL databases which will help me conserve space? What I should be learning now to solve such a problem?

Comment: your 48 `INT` columns should be `TINYINT` each. I don't see how the `ID` could be an `INT`, not even a `BIGINT` is large enough, maybe a `VARCHAR(21)` should do

Comment: Thanks @Lamak , I will really consider it. But it'll be helpful if you could guide me further.

Comment: Can you store the matrix in a single BIGINT column? I saw the documentation and it can only store 19 digit max, but you have 32 digit integer there. Even if you store it bit by bit, 5 kind of data require 3 bit, 3 times 32 is 96 bit and BIGINT only 64 bit.

Comment: Do you need filtering/grouping/searching based on your data?

Comment: Not going to happen. Where exactly do you have this set of data?

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan Yes,, i need to do searches..

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz The data will be generated dynamically

Comment: Has I said - not going to happen.

Comment: What will be a possible/better way ? @DuduMarkovitz

Comment: Have you ever calculated how much time it is going to take to generate the data?

Comment: no. :) @DuduMarkovitz

Comment: Please estimate and share :-)

Comment: sorry but i guess i need to think about generating it only after knowing how to store it , right?

Comment: No, first estimate.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Every relational database is a "SQL database"